# Array cannot be formed from single element in NSMutableDictionary -[__NSCFString count]:

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm setting objects to my NSMutableDictionary like this

```
if ([detail isEqualToString:[check objectAtIndex:1]]) {//check is NSArray,getdict is NSMutableDictionary,keyverify is NSMutableArray


        if ([getdict objectForKey:detail]==nil) {

            [getdict setObject:[check objectAtIndex:2] forKey:detail];
            [keyverify addObject:[check objectAtIndex:2]];
        }

        else{

            [keyverify addObject:[check objectAtIndex:2]];
            [getdict setObject:keyverify forKey:detail];

        }

        }
           NSArray * passarray=[getdict valueForKey:detail];
```

when my NSMutableDictionary value is like this

```
dict:{
"Sample" =     (
    "Test1",
    Test2,
    Test3
);
}
```

i can get an array from NSMutableDictionary and displayed in UITableView but when i get my NSMutableDictionary value like this

```
dict:{
"Sample" = Test1;
}
```

my app crashes with an log

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6eab4c0'
```

Kindly help me pls..Thanks..

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the lines that get the error.  But basically you're getting an NSString where you probably are expecting an NSArray.  With JSON what you get this time is not always the same as what you got last time.

Comment: Hint:  Learn how to use [isKindOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject).

Answer (score 1):

In your second test case the key "Sample" is not an array that is why you get that error.

You can check this by using isKindOfClass : [NSArray class], if it passes the condition then it is an array and you can do the array methods you want to if it is not then get the key "Sample" as a string.